# SSL site won't load non-SSL scripts from other domain

Tags: javascript, css, http, ssl, https

I have a website with SSL (https instead of http).  I am attempting to embed a widget that references files (js, css) from another domain.  This other domain does not have SSL (http instead of https).  As a result, I get an net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE and the widget will not load.

How can I tell my site to allow the insecure content used by the widget?

Comment: in modern browsers, you can't

Comment: @JaromandaX Any way of using .htaccess to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't follow. What do you think you can do with .htaccess on your site to change some other site?

Comment: I was thinking there may be some way to call the insecure scripts from some sub-folder on my website, but as I explained to @William Patton, the main function of the widget is a GET to the other website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell a website to allow insecure content in the page as it is not the site that is blocking access to the scripts - it's the Browser.

When using SSL the browser puts a minimum level of security on the connection and ensures that no unencrypted connections are being made from the page. This stops any unencrypted connections being used to transmit data in the requests.

The simplest option I can think of to work around this is to host the scripts yourself on the domain that is secured by SSL. It may or may not be possible to edit the widget easily so it uses the locally hosted script instead of the ones from the non-https site.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how things work.  I tried hosting the content but the main function of the widget performs a GET to the other site, so I can't host the most important part.

Comment: That is unfortunate the logic requires the scripts to be hosted at their own server. Since that is the case the only other suggestion i have is to contact the widget hosted and request they implement SSL. Mention letsencrypy as it is a very popular certificate authority that provides free certs, easy to install and configure, that are trusted by all of the most common browsers. Hopefully you can get some kind of resolution or workaround. Going luck with project!